# Wait for hotkey?

Tags: scripting, user-defined-functions, autoit, hotkeys

I'm wondering why my script doesn't wait for me to send the hotkey <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd>?

```
WinWaitActive("Open")
HotKeySet("+!q", "ClickFill")
Func ClickFill()
    ControlClick("Open", "", "[CLASS:32770]")
    ControlSend("Open", "", "[CLASS:32770]", "C:\au3")
    Exit
```

The script just exits after the 'Open' dialog becomes active.  I'm trying to get the script to click on **class 32770**, which is the address bar, then send the au3 directory to it, which is my autoit scripts directory.  My hope is that the script will always stay open, so any time I try to open something, it works.

**Second attempt**

```
WinWaitActive("Open")
HotKeySet("+!q", "ClickFill")

While(1)
    Sleep(1000)
WEnd

Func ClickFill()
    ControlClick("Open", "", "[CLASS:32770]")
    ControlSend("Open", "", "[CLASS:32770]", "C:\au3")
    Exit
```

The script remains open, but the hotkey is not effective.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you just need to close your function with a "EndFunc". This works for me.

```
WinWaitActive("Open")
HotKeySet("+!q", "ClickFill")

While(1)
    Sleep(1000)
WEnd

Func ClickFill()
    MsgBox(262144,"","Look I work!")

    ControlClick("Open", "", "[CLASS:32770]")
    ControlSend("Open", "", "[CLASS:32770]", "C:\au3")
    Exit
EndFunc
```

Here is some working code for Notepad++

```
Global $g_hWinHandle, $g_hOpenWin

;set hotkey
HotKeySet("+!q", "ClickFill")

;open notepad++
ShellExecute(@ProgramFilesDir & "\notepad++\notepad++.exe")

;wait for notepad++ window
WinWait("[Class:Notepad++]")
If @error Then Exit

;get notepad++ window handle
$g_hWinHandle = WinGetHandle("[Class:Notepad++]")

;make sure the window is active
WinActivate($g_hWinHandle)
WinWaitActive($g_hWinHandle)

;open "Open" dialog
WinMenuSelectItem($g_hWinHandle, "", "&File", "&Open...")

;wait for "Open" dialog window
WinWaitActive("Open")

;get the "Open" dialog window handle
$g_hOpenWin = WinGetHandle("Open")
If @error Then Exit

;wait for hotkey
While (1)
    Sleep(1000)
WEnd

Func ClickFill()
    ;make sure the window is active
    WinActivate($g_hOpenWin)
    WinWaitActive($g_hOpenWin)

    ;focus the toolbar
    ControlFocus($g_hOpenWin, "", "[CLASS:ToolbarWindow32; INSTANCE:3]")
    ControlCommand($g_hOpenWin, "", "[CLASS:ToolbarWindow32; INSTANCE:3]", "SendCommandID", "1280")

    ;send our command to the toolbar
    ControlSetText($g_hOpenWin, "", "Edit2", "C:\au3")
    ControlSend($g_hOpenWin, "", "Edit2", "{ENTER}")

    Exit
EndFunc   ;==>ClickFill
```

In the above example you will see that I use ControlFocus and   ControlCommand on the ToolbarWindow32 control. Most dialog windows have a ToolbarWindow32 control. To simulate clicking on them you have to use ControlCommand with the SendCommandID option. You can get that ID under the toolbar tab in the AutoIt info tool. However, you will see that once the ToolbarWindow32 control is clicked on it gives focus to an edit control. That edit control is what you need to send text to if you want to change directories. Finding that edit control with the AutoIt tool can be a bit tricky. You will have to make sure "Freeze" is unchecked under options.

[image]

If you are still having problems with the code I would recommend that you first make sure you can get the code working without a hotkey. Then try it with a one letter hotkey and then lastly try it with your multiple hotkey combination. With out having access to your computer I am just guessing but I suspect that you are not accessing the address bar right. There might also be a program running on your computer that is using the same hotkey.

Comment: Yeah, when the "Open" dialog is open in Notepad++, the hotkey still seems to do nothing, and then the script just exits.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work at all....  The hotkey doesn't change what's in the edit2 classnn.  I'm using notepad++ as a sample program.  The endgame goal is to be able to do this for all the 'open' dialogs that pop up.  But even being able to do this for notepad would be nice.  Simply being able to identify what needs to be targeted, so that I don't have to use unreliable mouseclicks is the purpose of the question, you know?  Using mouse clicks to activate the address bar is unreliable because sometimes people move the window, and the window is permanently moved, so the script is broken for a bit.

Comment: What happens, though: the open dialog pops up, but pressing alt-shift-q does not fill the address bar.  So, I shouldn't say 'doesn't work at all'.

Comment: I added some more clarification to the post that should help.

Comment: Why do you name your variables "g_" when you don't use local Variables as well? It's probably just confusing for someone with "beginner" problems... ;-)

Comment: When I first started programming I had a lot of trouble with my programs because I didn’t understand the importance of variable scope. This was mostly due to people giving me sloppy examples. I eventually learned what I was doing wrong and had to go back and correct my bad coding habits. I could have saved myself a lot of trouble if I would have just used the recommended best coding practices from the beginning. That is why I try to use proper variable naming in my examples (even simple ones). Also see: [Best Coding Practices](https://www.autoitscript.com/wiki/Best_coding_practices)